# 2D recurrence relation $p_{n+1,k+1}=(n-2k)(p_{n,k+1}+p_{n,k})$

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations, generating-functions

I am trying to solve the recurrence relation $$p_{n+1,k+1}=(n-2k)(p_{n,k+1}+p_{n,k})$$ with initial condition $p_{0,k}=\delta_{k,0}$ (kronecker delta).

From the backwards version $p_{n,k}=(n-2k+1)(p_{n-1,k}+p_{n-1,k-1})$, I deduced that $p_{n,0}=(n+1)!$ and $p_{-n,k}=0$ for negative $-n$, so I am only interested in positive values of $n$ and $k$. If the factor $(n-2k)$ was not there, it would be the binomial coefficients, so I was hoping to find an explicit expression for $p_{n,k}$, but as of now I haven't been able to make much progress.

Comment: Simple-looking recurrences like this can be very complicated.  For example, simpler recurrences than yours give rise to Stirling numbers of both kinds.  If you define $q_{n, k}$ by $p_{n, k} = (n - 2k + 1)! \cdot q_{n, k}$ then the resulting recurrence shows that the $q_{n, k}$ are still integers, and maybe it is easier to deal with.  (But I'm not extremely optimistic.)

Comment: It seems that $\frac{p_{n,k}}{(n+1)!}$ is a rational polynomial of degree $k$ for $n \geq 2k$ (and $p_{n,k}=0$ otherwise so it doesn't matter there). For example $p_{n,1}=\frac{(n-1)}{3}(n+1)!$, $p_{n,2}=\frac{(n-3)(5n-8)}{90}(n+1)!$ and so on.